# Creating nodes directly by SQL

Tags: nodes, flags, database

I am creating (content/nodes)  directly by SQL , I am inserting following tables :
node 
node_revision 
body_field

everything looks ok . But when I use FLAG module it does'nt show anything on the bookmarked view . Am i missing any other table which should be updated ?

Thanks 
pks

Comment: Wouldn't recommend doing it in SQL. Set up a custom module, use the node_save function and set up an appropriate array, instead.

Answer (score 5):

Every time you create a node in SQL, God kills a kitten. There are multiple hooks that fire on node creation, that make sure that a new node is processed corectly. The correct way to create a node is with a node_save() function. It will fire the correct hooks, and register the node where it should. Please refer https://drupal.org/node/1388922